# Call evaluateJavascript from a SwiftUI button

Tags: javascript, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

Assume you have this WKWebView implementation:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

class WebViewData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var parsedText: NSAttributedString? = nil

    var isInit = false
    var shouldUpdateView = true
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    @ObservedObject var data: WebViewData

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        context.coordinator.view.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return context.coordinator.view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard data.shouldUpdateView else {
            data.shouldUpdateView = false
            return
        }

        let html = """
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    \(text)

                <script>
                    let isScrolling = false;
                    let timer;

                    function toggleScrolling() {
                        if(!isScrolling) {
                            timer = setInterval(function() {
                                window.scrollBy(0, 1);
                            }, \(80 / autoScrollVelocity));
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(timer)
                        }

                        isScrolling = !isScrolling;
                    }
                </script>
                </body>
            </html>
        """

        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator {
        return WebViewCoordinator(view: self)
    }
}

class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let view: WebView

    init(view: WebView) {
        self.view = view

        super.init()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !self.view.data.isInit {
                self.view.data.isInit = true
                // useless text parsing here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in this view

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ReadingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var webViewData = WebViewData()
    private let text: String

    init(text: String?) {
        self.text = text ?? "Sorry, this reading is empty"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Auto scroll") {
                ??????
            }
            WebView(title: self.title, text: self.text, data: self.webViewData)
        }
        .onReceive(self.webViewData.$parsedText, perform: { parsedText in
            if let parsedText = parsedText {
               print(parsedText)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now, in the button with label `Auto scroll`, how is it possible to call the javascript inside the html `toggleScrolling()` (or moving this code in a WKUserScript if necessary)? I'm pretty lost here.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm going to address the question itself (calling `evaluateJavascript` from a SwiftUI button) and not necessarily the javascript itself (your `toggleScrolling` function), which I haven't tested.*

I think this is a great opportunity to use Combine (which means you have to make sure to `import Combine` at the top of your file) to pass messages between the views through the `ObservableObject` you have set up.

Here's the final code (I had to change a few minor things about the original that wouldn't compile):

```
class WebViewData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var parsedText: NSAttributedString? = nil

    var functionCaller = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()
    
    var isInit = false
    var shouldUpdateView = true
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    @StateObject var data: WebViewData

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webview = WKWebView()
        webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard data.shouldUpdateView else {
            data.shouldUpdateView = false
            return
        }

        context.coordinator.tieFunctionCaller(data: data)
        context.coordinator.webView = uiView
        
        let html = """
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    \(text)

                <script>
                    function doAlert() { document.body.innerHTML += "hi"; }
                </script>
                </body>
            </html>
        """

        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator {
        return WebViewCoordinator(view: self)
    }
}

class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var parent: WebView
    var webView: WKWebView? = nil

    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init(view: WebView) {
        self.parent = view
        super.init()
    }
    
    func tieFunctionCaller(data: WebViewData) {
        cancellable = data.functionCaller.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
            self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("doAlert()")
        })
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !self.parent.data.isInit {
                self.parent.data.isInit = true
                // useless text parsing here...
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ReadingView: View {
    @StateObject var webViewData = WebViewData()
    var text : String

    init(text: String?) {
        self.text = text ?? "Sorry, this reading is empty"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Call javascript") {
                webViewData.functionCaller.send()
            }
            WebView(text: text, data: webViewData)
        }
        .onReceive(webViewData.$parsedText, perform: { parsedText in
            if let parsedText = parsedText {
               print(parsedText)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

#### What happens?

1. There's a `PassthroughSubject` on `WebViewData` that doesn't take an actual value (it just takes `Void`) that is used to send a signal from the SwiftUI view to the `WebViewCoordinator`.
2. The `WebViewCoordinator` subscribes to that publisher and runs `evaluateJavasscript`. In order to do this, it has to have a reference to the `WKWebView`, which you can see I pass along in `updateUIView`
3. You weren't actually returning a `WKWebView` in `makeUIView` (or maybe you were but the simplified code for the question had mangled it a bit)

Comment: THANKS, THANKS, THANKS. I had to ditch StateObject in favor of ObservableObject for IOS13 compatibility. It work like a charm.