# SwiftUI: Highlighting Text with different colors using WkWebView

Tags: swiftui, uikit, wkwebview

I am trying to use swiftUI to be able to create a custom EPUB reader. Ive looked around at some but none fit my needs. I want to be able to customize it. The issue I have ran into is being able to Highlight text while reading either Orange, blue, green, etc. When highlight a text and then the menu bar pops up and I click on my custom MenuBar color the app crashes. I found this article on highlighting text but uses the UIkit and not SwiftUI. Ive been trying to "translate"(not sure what the correct term is)it to use it with SwiftUI but crashes due to unrecognized selector.Im thinking I am not setting up the things correct. Not sure if it is worth using SwiftUI anymore and just switching my app to UIKit at this point since I have not been able to find many resources using swiftUI. Here is article to highlight text  : https://dailong.medium.com/highlight-text-in-wkwebview-1659a19715e6
Just started learning swiftUI so not sure if the way the WebView is setup is correct.

Here is the gitHub link to all of the code https://github.com/longvudai/demo/tree/master/highlight-webview/highlight-webview With the SwiftUI all i did was copy and paste the files. Only difference is with SwiftUI was wrapping the WebView other than that everything else is the same.

SWIFTUI

```
   `struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: CustomView?
    var serializedObject: SerializedObject?
    private var dataStack = Stack<Highlights>()
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView?, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.webView = webView as? CustomView
    }
    
    // receive message from wkwebview
    func userContentController(
        _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
        didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
    ) {
        if let markerHandler = MarkerScript.Handler(message) {
            guard
                let dataString = message.body as? String,
                let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
                else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let serialized = try? decoder.decode(
                SerializedObject.self,
                from: data
                ) else { return }
            receiveMarkerMessage(markerHandler, data: serialized)
        }
    }
    
    func receiveMarkerMessage(_ handler: MarkerScript.Handler, data: SerializedObject) {
        switch handler {
        case .serialize:
            serializedObject = data
            
            // your callback here
            
            let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.clearSelection()
            self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
        case .erase:
            serializedObject = data
            let highlights = data.highlights
            let listId = highlights.map { $0.id }
            guard let top = dataStack.top  else { return }
            let newData = top.filter { listId.contains($0.id) }
            if newData != top {
                dataStack.push(newData)
            }
        }
    }
    func highlight(_ color: MarkerColor) {
        let script =
            MarkerScript.Evaluate.highlightSelectedTextWithColor(color)
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
        print("highlightfunction")
    }
    
    func removeAll() {
        let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.removeAllHighlights()
        self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
        dataStack.push([])
    }
    
    func erase() {
        let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.erase()
        self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
    }
    
    
    @objc func highlightthiscolor() {
        highlight(MarkerColor.orange)
    }
    
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator()
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomView {
    let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let uc = configuration.userContentController
    uc.addUserScript(WKUserScript.injectViewPort())
    
    // Jquery
    uc.addUserScript(JQueryScript.core())
    
    // Rangy
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.core())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.classapplier())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.highlighter())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.selectionsaverestore())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.textrange())
    
    // Marker
    uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.css())
    uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.jsScript())
    
    uc.add(coordinator, name: MarkerScript.Handler.serialize.rawValue)
    uc.add(coordinator, name: MarkerScript.Handler.erase.rawValue)
    
    let _wkwebview = CustomView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    _wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator
    
    return _wkwebview
}

func updateUIView(_ webView: CustomView, context: Context) {
    guard let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "html") else { return }
    let localHTMLUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
    webView.loadFileURL(localHTMLUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: localHTMLUrl)
    addCustomContextMenu()
}


func addCustomContextMenu(){
    //Has to be type of WKWebView
    let colorOrange:UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Orange", action: #selector(Coordinator.highlightthiscolor))
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [colorOrange]
}

}`
```

UIKit

```
protocol MarkerLogic {
func erase()
func highlight(_ color: MarkerColor)
func removeAll()
 }

 class Marker: NSObject {
 weak var webView: WKWebView?
 var serializedObject: SerializedObject?
 private var dataStack = Stack<Highlights>()
 }

 extension Marker: MarkerLogic {
  func highlight(_ color: MarkerColor) {
    let script =
        MarkerScript.Evaluate.highlightSelectedTextWithColor(color)
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
}

func removeAll() {
    let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.removeAllHighlights()
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
    dataStack.push([])
}

func erase() {
    let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.erase()
    webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
}
 }

 // MARK: - WKScriptMessageHandler
extension Marker: WKScriptMessageHandler {
func userContentController(
    _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
    didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
) {
    if let markerHandler = MarkerScript.Handler(message) {
        guard
            let dataString = message.body as? String,
            let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
            else { return }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let serialized = try? decoder.decode(
            SerializedObject.self,
            from: data
            ) else { return }
        receiveMarkerMessage(markerHandler, data: serialized)
    }
}
func receiveMarkerMessage(_ handler: MarkerScript.Handler, data: SerializedObject) {
    switch handler {
    case .serialize:
        serializedObject = data
        
        // your callback here
        
        let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.clearSelection()
        webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
    case .erase:
        serializedObject = data
        let highlights = data.highlights
        let listId = highlights.map { $0.id }
        guard let top = dataStack.top  else { return }
        let newData = top.filter { listId.contains($0.id) }
        if newData != top {
            dataStack.push(newData)
        }
    }
}
}
```

--- ViewDidLoad

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
let marker: Marker = Marker()

let orangeButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.tag = 0
    v.backgroundColor = MarkerColor.orange.value
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(highlight(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return v
}()

let cyanButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.tag = 1
    v.backgroundColor = MarkerColor.cyan.value
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(highlight(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return v
}()

let pinkButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.tag = 2
    v.backgroundColor = MarkerColor.pink.value
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(highlight(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return v
}()

let eraseButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setTitle("Erase", for: .normal)
    v.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
    
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(erase), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return v
}()

let eraseAllButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton(type: .close)
    
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(eraseAll), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return v
}()

lazy var toolBars: UIStackView = {
    let v = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [orangeButton, cyanButton, pinkButton, eraseButton, eraseAllButton])
    v.axis = .horizontal
    v.distribution = .fillEqually
    v.spacing = 20
    return v
}()



// This is to make the makeUIView
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let uc = config.userContentController
    
    uc.addUserScript(WKUserScript.injectViewPort())
    
    // Jquery
    uc.addUserScript(JQueryScript.core())
    
    // Rangy
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.core())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.classapplier())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.highlighter())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.selectionsaverestore())
    uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.textrange())
    
    // Marker
    uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.css())
    uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.jsScript())
    
    uc.add(self.marker, name: MarkerScript.Handler.serialize.rawValue)
    uc.add(self.marker, name: MarkerScript.Handler.erase.rawValue)
    
    let v = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    marker.webView = webView
    
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "html")!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    
    let views = [webView, toolBars]
    views.forEach {
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        
        toolBars.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        toolBars.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        toolBars.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        toolBars.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
}

// MARK: - Selector
@objc func highlight(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        marker.highlight(MarkerColor.orange)
    case 1:
        marker.highlight(MarkerColor.cyan)
    case 2:
        marker.highlight(MarkerColor.pink)
    default:
        break
    }
}

@objc func erase() {
    marker.erase()
}

@objc func eraseAll() {
    marker.removeAll()
}

// MARK: - WKScriptMessageHandler
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
}
```

}

Comment: What you've included isn't enough to reproduce your issue -- there are many missing types you haven't included.

Comment: @jnpdx I felt like adding all of the code would be too much. I have the git hub link if that would help Sorry.

Comment: Ideally, you'd pare it down to a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx From my understanding the errors are coming from my webView Wrapper. Which is the code I posted above. All i did was wrap the webview from the UIkit in order to use it in swiftUI using the UIViewRepresentable. But when I launch the app the html loads fine. The problem is when i highlight a word then click on the color I want from my customMenu tool bar the app crashes. Which is why im leaning towards it being the WebView: UIViewRepresentable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the code working by looking at the post: [Call evaluateJavascript from a SwiftUI button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581811/call-evaluatejavascript-from-a-swiftui-button). The problem I was running into was the fact that I was not able to run the javascript func in order to highlight. Using `Combine` i was able to make a button in the View and when that button is clicked being able to run the javascript code. Will post the code below for anyone who is interested.

```swift
import WebKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class WebViewData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var parsedText: NSAttributedString? = nil
    
    var functionCaller = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()
    
    var isInit = false
    var shouldUpdateView = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var webViewData = WebViewData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                webViewData.functionCaller.send()
                
            }) {
                Text("Orange")
            }
            WebView(data: webViewData)
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @StateObject var data: WebViewData
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        //var webView: WKWebView?
        var serializedObject: SerializedObject?
        private var dataStack = Stack<Highlights>()
        var parent: WebView
        var webView: WKWebView? = nil
        private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
        
        init(view: WebView) {
            self.parent = view
            super.init()
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.webView = webView
        }
        
        // receive message from wkwebview
        func userContentController(
            _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
            didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
        ) {
            if let markerHandler = MarkerScript.Handler(message) {
                guard
                    let dataString = message.body as? String,
                    let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
                else { return }
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                guard let serialized = try? decoder.decode(
                    SerializedObject.self,
                    from: data
                ) else { return }
                receiveMarkerMessage(markerHandler, data: serialized)
            }
        }
        
        func receiveMarkerMessage(_ handler: MarkerScript.Handler, data: SerializedObject) {
            switch handler {
            case .serialize:
                serializedObject = data
                // your callback here
                let script = MarkerScript.Evaluate.clearSelection()
                self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript(script)
            case .erase:
                serializedObject = data
                let highlights = data.highlights
                let listId = highlights.map { $0.id }
                guard let top = dataStack.top  else { return }
                let newData = top.filter { listId.contains($0.id) }
                if newData != top {
                    dataStack.push(newData)
                }
            }
        }
        func tieFunctionCaller(data: WebViewData) {
            cancellable = data.functionCaller.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("highlightSelectedTextWithColor('orange')")
            })
        }
    
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(view: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        
        let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let uc = configuration.userContentController
        uc.addUserScript(WKUserScript.injectViewPort())
        
        // Jquery
        uc.addUserScript(JQueryScript.core())
        
        // Rangy
        uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.core())
        uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.classapplier())
        uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.highlighter())
        uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.selectionsaverestore())
        uc.addUserScript(RangyScript.textrange())
        
        // Marker
        uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.css())
        uc.addUserScript(MarkerScript.jsScript())
        uc.add(coordinator, name: MarkerScript.Handler.serialize.rawValue)
        uc.add(coordinator, name: MarkerScript.Handler.erase.rawValue)
        
        let _wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        _wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator
        
        return _wkwebview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
        guard data.shouldUpdateView else {
            data.shouldUpdateView = false
            return
        }
        context.coordinator.tieFunctionCaller(data: data)
        context.coordinator.webView = webView
        
        guard let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "html") else { return }
        let localHTMLUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
        webView.loadFileURL(localHTMLUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: localHTMLUrl)
    }
    
}
```

[image]